# json.net: prevent ulong from getting serialized in scientific notation

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I have a `ulong` which I want to serialize to `JSON`. However, it gets serialized in scientific notation with data loss... How can I prevent that? I think I could convert it to a string but I'm not sure if this is a good idea...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JavaScript does not support enough of numeric range to show ulong, so it does not make sense to represent it as numeric value in JSON.

If JSON ever will be used by JavaScript you'd better convert such values to string before/during conversion.

One possible conversion option - [WCF & JSON: Serialize long as string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13700925/wcf-json-serialize-long-as-string) or use `decimal` as suggested [Json.NET crashes when serializing unsigned integer (ulong) array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9355091/json-net-crashes-when-serializing-unsigned-integer-ulong-array).